# Quick question regarding matrices of bilinear forms (finding an orthogonal basis)

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, I've got the form $\langle A,B \rangle = tr(AB)$ and the vector space of real $2 \times 2$ matrices. The question wants me to determine the matrix of the form with respect to the standard basis of matrix units. I've already done this and got the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now it wants me to find an orthogonal basis for the above form, and I'm unsure whether I should be using Gram-Schmidt on $\left\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \right\}$ where

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $v_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Or on the standard basis of matrix units.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure about the definition of the form? Gram-Schmidt only works for inner product spaces. In fact, taking the basis $\{e_1,e_4,\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(e_2+e_3),\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(e_2-e_3)\}$, the matrix will be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the signature is invariant under base change. Hence it is impossible to find an orthogonal basis. It works, however, if you take $tr(AB^t)$ instead. In this case the standard basis is already orthonormal.

Edit (to address confusion of OP):
Most authors will define an orthogonal basis as a basis $\{b_1,\cdots, b_n\}$ such that $\left<b_i,b_j\right>=\delta_{ij}$. If you use this definition, then the argument above shows that there is no orthogonal basis.

However, there is a weaker definition where you only require $\left<b_i,b_j\right>=\pm\delta_{ij}$. Then, the basis I characterised above is an orthogonal basis. This weaker definition is non-standard in some sense and should be explicitly indicated. The 'usual' Gram-Schmidt doesn't work here, but I am sure that there is a suitable adaptation as mentioned by @rschwieb. Generally any basis should work (to answer the initial question), but I assume that this modified Gram-Schmidt needs non-isotrope base-vectors to work (which neither the suggested basis nor the standard basis are).

Finally, if you modify the form to $tr(AB^t)$, you will also get a different matrix representing this form. In fact it will be the identity matrix. Thus the standard basis is already orthogonal.

Comment: Yep, that is definitely the form. I've also confirmed that matrix is also correct. The full question is here (question 5) in case I've caused some confusion with my original post. http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2012/2632/6/Linear_Algebra_II_PS4.pdf

Comment: +1 There is an adaptation of Gram-Schmidt that works for any signature (usually used in proofs of Sylvester's law of inertia). In the book I'm thinking of, they define an orthonormal basis to be "pairwise orthogonal with elements having $B(x,x)\in\{-1,0,1\}$". I know many people find that a little distasteful, though...

Comment: @rschwieb Am I misunderstanding the question? I'm unsure now.